# Excel opens 2nd blank workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little problem.
I started to experiment with macros recently. Since I started doing this every time I open any excel file, there is opened a 2nd file in the background.
My XLSTART folder is empty. After saving this 2nd file into the XLSTART folder I do not have to save the new file anymore. 
So my idea is to program a macro that closes this file automatically on start. 
The only problem here is that I first have to load every workbook that I want to open. 
So if I start a file first things first the empty file will be opened and after this one the file I originally wanted to be open. 
If I close the empty file before the other one loaded it will open a new 3rd file. So in the end I open one file, automatically open+close the blank one but after loading the right file it creates a new file.
So my question now is: How can I delay my open macro so that the other file loads. 
So far I got this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), Windows("a.xlsm").Close
End Sub
```

But the close event is not delayed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.OnTime` takes a string parameter to identify a procedure to run after waiting. You would need to change your setup to something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "CloseWorkbook"
End Sub

Public Sub CloseWorkbook() 'put this sub in a standard module
    Windows("a.xlsm").Close
End Sub
```

Alternatively, use `Application.Wait`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
    Windows("a.xlsm").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, sorry last week i had a lot of work to do. I tried both versions out. Using the first one it says that the method CloseWorkbook is not available.

Comment: Did you put it in a standard module?

Comment: Using the second version excel starts with a delay. After the delay, it opens the workbook I wanted+ a completely new one (not the one with the macro)

Comment: Yeah ok that was my problem sorry. Thank you very much. So the first code works fine for me. :)